# Recognition of Previous Marriage by the Roman Catholic Church

Tags: catholicism, marriage, annulment

In a situation in which a non-Catholic, previously married to a non-Catholic, subsequently  marries a Catholic outside the Catholic Church, is it possible to have a Catholic marriage for the latest marriage - or recognition of that marriage - without obtaining an decree of nullity for the prior marriage?

Comment: We do not feel that we are qualified to give pastoral advice, that is something which requires some personal contact. Please consult your Pastor.

Comment: @MattGutting and Bye - Usually I'm quick to vote to close, but this ***could*** be interpreted as asking what the official Catholic doctrine is, which ***would*** be on-topic.  Although it would be far simpler to talk to a Priest in the Catholic Church, particularly the Priest of the Church you'd like to get married in.  There may be some flexibility that varies from Priest to priest...

Comment: This question appears to be be two separate questions: "Can the Church judge a marriage between two non-Catholics invalid?" and, if so, "Does the Church allow mixed (Catholic & non-Catholic) marriages?"

Answer (score 2):

*(Answering having read the original post prior to the edit)*

1. The marriage of a Catholic who marries outside the Church is invalid [cf. [Can.  1108 §1.](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P40.HTM)]. Such a Catholic ought to contact their priest for the steps required for their reconciliation to the Church.
2. Another complication to address with the priest is that the Catholic is in a relationship with a person the Catholic Church considers married.
3. For a non-Catholic previously married and divorced and now wishing to marry a Catholic, they are to note from my answer linked below:

> a. No marriage can occur until their prior marriage that ended in divorce is examined by the Church and a decree of nullity issued (i.e. in the eyes of the Church, that marriage never existed to begin with).
>
> b. Once that decree has been issued, the requirements for a [mixed
>   marriage](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/_P41.HTM) must be met
>   for there to be a valid marriage in the Catholic Church.

---

**Endnote**

[My answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31588/do-divorced-non-catholics-need-an-annulment-to-marry-in-the-catholic-church/31591#31591) to [Do divorced non-Catholics need an annulment to marry in the Catholic Church?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31588/do-divorced-non-catholics-need-an-annulment-to-marry-in-the-catholic-church) stated:

> Thus the Church recognizes the marriages of non-Catholics as well and
>   considers them valid until proven otherwise.